# Is it possible to White Label Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, branding

Is it possible to white label the Ubuntu One to sell as part of a service to an existing customer? I would like to use my brand for consistency purposes.

Answer (score 7):

No, it isn't possible to whitelabel Ubuntu One.